# I want to Remove an old app in my AppStore Connect

Tags: applications, app-store-connect

I have one app that is removed from sale individually but also still for sale in a bundle. Still,the option "Remove App" appears in "App Information" Section.

But as I pressed it, Apple says I cannot remove an app that is in an App Bundle. Well make sense. So I goto the app bundle and uncheck the "Cleared for Sale" box and save it. Then I open the bundle, where it says "Edit" I clicked on it and was able to remove the same app from bundle. Saved it and it brought me to main page of the bundle, and when I try to click Save there, it says

> Error encountered saving or updating bundle: Attempt to add or remove
>   apps from a bundle that does not allow editing.
>
> Attempt to add or remove apps from a bundle that does not allow
>   editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add or remove apps from a bundle that has already been approved for sale.

[Source](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/App%20Bundles_Creating%20And%20Managing%20App%20Bundles)

> ### Can I add or remove apps from an app bundle?
>
> You can only add or remove apps from an app bundle before it has been
>   approved by App Review. If your app bundle has already been approved,
>   you must create a new app bundle.

Create a new bundle with the apps you want, then retire the old bundle or perhaps at this point, contacting the apple developer store support team would be wise if you’re not certain how bundles work for removal. Making two bundles when you don’t like the one bundle you already made might not help things.

Comment: What does the last sentence even mean? Creating a new app bundle with same apps will enable me to delete the old bundle? I am confused.

Comment: 1) Create a new bundle that doesn't contain the app that you don't want and then 2) retire the old bundle with the app you don't want.

Comment: Thanks @dwightk for the clarification and bmike for improving the answer.

Comment: This is not even an answer. Actually the answer is I cannot remove a bundle that I created. Hence any apps that was added to a bundle will not be able to be removed and remains in my Appstore Connect as clutter.

Comment: This is the answer to your question.  I said that you can't add or remove apps from a bundle.  That is the answer to your question.  @dwightk added additional info about how you can work around Apple's limitations.  What more do you want?

Comment: Also, dwight workaround is not what i need really. My problem isnt in the bundle contents. My problem is i want to clean up my Apps page in AppStore Connect. Id like to totally remove apps that been removed from sale (they are bad apps really). Kind of surprised that Apple won't allow it. Very bad design of Apps Store connect.